# localStorage .parse .stringify

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I need help with pushing 2 data values into localStorage. I know a little about the stringify and parse methods but cant grasp how to implement them.The 2 data values are from "Scores" and "saveName"(a username that is put into an input box).

```
var Score = (answeredCorrect * 20) + (timeleft);
var saveName = document.querySelector("#saveName");
function Storage() {
  localStorage.setItem("User", JSON.stringify(saveName.value));
  localStorage.setItem("Scores", JSON.stringify(Score));
  var GetStorage = localStorage.getItem("User");
  var GetStorage2 = localStorage.getItem("Scores");
  return {
    first:console.log("GetStorage: "+ GetStorage + GetStorage2),
    second:GetStorage,
    third:GetStorage2,
  };
};
var values = Storage();
var first = values.first;
var second = values.second;
var third = values.third;
```

Comment: Note Storage is a global window object, not a good name for a user function

Comment: There's really no need to stringify/parse primitive values (String and Number) that you are using ... however, you would just wrap `localStorage.getItem("User");` in `JSON.parse()` and your code would work not add `"` to the `User` value - e.g. `var GetStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User"));`

Comment: no point in getting the item after you have just stored it as you already have the value in saveName and Score, also console.log returns undefined not what it outputs

Comment: When user opens the page:
  `user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));  score = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score"));`
Note: First time/not saved, both will be `null`.
Before user leaves/to save:
  `localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  localStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(score));`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you need to parse it once retrieved from storage with JSON.parse, also naming Storage should be avoided.

Since your making a wrapper for localstorage, it could be done like this:

```
const Store = {
  set: (key, value) => localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value),
  get: key => JSON.parse(localStorage[key])
}
```

Then you can simply call it like the following, with a `set` and `get` methods:

```
//
Store.set('Score', Score)
Score = Store.get('Score')

//
Store.set('User', saveName.value)
saveName = Store.get('User')
```

Though you only need to `get()` on page load as you already have the value in Score/saveName etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried this and it doesnt help me with keeping the values in localStorage. I need to add values to both the user name and score areas of the localStorage array so that when the page is refreshed (and a new user enters their name) I can display all the the users along with their score.